# How do I implement the toString() method for an ArrayStack?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, tostring, displayobject

I want to display a list of orders of type  `ArrayQueue <Order>`
 The class `Order` has an `ArrayStack<String>` as one of its attributes.  I overrode the `toString()` method in the class `Order`, but how do I override it in the `ArrayStack` class? Because this is the output I get when I display:

*OrderNumber Name  Date  **ArrayStack@481adc30***

What would I have to do to display the Strings in ArrayStack correctly? Do I make changes to class ArrayStack or change something in my Display method?

This is my Display method:

```
 public void display(){
    if (!isEmpty())
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
        System.out.println(queue[(frontIndex + i) % queue.length]);
    }
    else System.out.println("You don't have any orders");
    }
```

ArrayStack Class:

```
 public class ArrayStack < T > implements StackInterface < T >
{
    private T [] stack; // array of stack entries

    private int topIndex; // index of top entry

    private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 50;

    public ArrayStack ()
    {
        this (DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    } // end default constructor


    public ArrayStack (int initialCapacity)
    {
        // the cast is safe because the new array contains null entries
        @ SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
            T [] tempStack = (T []) new Object [initialCapacity];
        stack = tempStack;
        topIndex = -1;
    } // end constructor

    /*  Implementations of the stack operations */
```

Order Class:

```
   import java.util.Date;


public class Order {

    int orderNumber;
    String customerName;
    Date date;
    StackInterface <String> items;

Order( int number, String name, Date datum, StackInterface<String> item){
    orderNumber = number;
    customerName= name;
    date= datum;
    items = item;   
}

/Overriding toString() to Display a list of Orders as one String line. 
public String toString(){
    return orderNumber + " " + customerName + " " + date + " " + items;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `toString()` method of `Order` class.

Comment: `public String toString(){
 return orderNumber + " " + customerName + " " + date + " " + items;
}`

Comment: queue is the object of type `ArrayQueue <Order>`?

Comment: queue is the Array in the  `QueueArray()`  class  it's a generic type.

Comment: So the values of `orderNumber`, `customerName`, `date` are printed properly. Only you have problem with `items`?

Comment: Yes! They're printed correctly because I added a toString() method in class `Order` that displays the Array elements as Strings. But what if one of the Array Elements is an Array itself? in my case the `items`. I would have to somehow add a `toString()` method to that too? but where would I add it?

Comment: Can you tell me ArrayStack is bundled in which package?

Comment: I implemented it myself. I will add the ArrayStack and Orders Classes to my Question

Comment: you must add toString to ArrayStack < T > so it will be called when in `public String toString(){
    return orderNumber + " " + customerName + " " + date + " " + items;
}`

Comment: I have added toString method in ArrayStack in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `override toString()` method in `ArrayStack` as shown [`here`](http://faculty.washington.edu/moishe/javademos/ch06%20Code/jss2/ArrayStack.java). This will solve your problem.

```
public String toString() {
    String result = "";

    for (int scan = 0; scan < top; scan++)
        result = result + stack[scan].toString() + "\n";

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yaay! It kinda worked! but it displayed only the first item in the stack. Why? 

could it be a mistake in the way I added items to the stack?  

`int no = input.nextInt();
       StackInterface <String> items = new ArrayStack<String>(no);
       for(int j= 1; j<= no; j++){
        System.out.println("Enter item no: " + j );
        String theItem = input.next();
        items.push(theItem);
       }
       Order order1 = new Order (orderno, customername, real_date, items);
       orders.enqueue(order1);`

Comment: Please put it into your question, it is difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: Show the `push` method as well as `enqueue`
 method.

Comment: Nevermind. It worked now! It wasn't printing the last item but I changed `scan < top`  to `scan<=top`  and it works perfect now. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should do this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(queue.toArray()));
```

Comment: where would I add this?

Comment: you would add it to your in place of     `for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
        System.out.println(queue[(frontIndex + i) % queue.length]);
    }`

Comment: That would still print the ArrayStack attribute inside the ArrayQueue as  ArrayStack@481adc30 and it will also display nulls if I have only one object in my Queue

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(queue));
```

Comment: but that would print nulls if I have only one object in my queue

Comment: yep otherwise do the printout per Order.

Comment: It didn't fix the ArrayStack@481adc30  problem when I call Display

Comment: please put ArrayStack and Order codes in the question as well